# SignIn with google and add user data to Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, store, radix, account

I have written a code in which I use both signIn with email password and signIn with google, Now when a user signs up with his/her data from the form gets stored in the firestore and then I am able to retrieve the username, image, etc from firestore.
But when someone signs in with google then I don't have code to store the credentials to firestore and fetch the user details conditionally.
All I want to add the signin with google date to firestore.
following is my code please have a look

```
    class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  // final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;
  Future googleLogin() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    // final googleUser = _googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) return;
    // _user = googleUser as GoogleSignInAccount?;

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    final credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth!.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
//     try {
//       UserCredential firebaseUser =
//           await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credentials);
//       if (firebaseUser != null) {
//         // Check is already sign up
//         final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
//             .collection('users')
//             .where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.user!.uid)
//             .get();

// //userdata to update at firebase
// //passing this via constructor to the next page

//         Map<String, dynamic> userdata = {
//           'useremail': firebaseUser.user!.email,
//           'displayname': firebaseUser.user!.displayName,
//           'photoUrl': firebaseUser.user!.photoURL,
//           'userid': firebaseUser.user!.uid,
//         };

// // navigate . if you don't have context here you can pass this as a paramater to the
// // method. no issue if you call inside build or init

//         //userdata is map. just for handling easily
//         //you can also create simple variables and pass each value to them.
//       }

//       return firebaseUser;
//     } catch (error) {
//       print(error);
//     }

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credentials);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! You have some code commented. Does this code not work? Is that the problem?

Comment: Let me check again but no it's not adding a new user to firebase.